# Anonymous meeting join. Service does not allow a cross domain

Tags: skype, lync, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I am trying to use the anonymous meeting provided with in the UCWA sample code. The developer sandbox works fine when I use the metio.net domain but when I try to use my companies domain we get a error message: "Service does not allow a cross domain request from this origin". So when I went to use the Anonymous meeting join and changing the domain with in the AnonMeeting.js to my companies domain I get the same error. I tried the only other option available on the index page, which is My own topology. I used my Skype for business login and gives me the 403 error with the same console message "Service does not allow a cross domain request from this origin". At the company I am at we use Skype for business online.

When we enter the URL http://lyncdiscover.domain.com we get to the xml tree fine but if its https we need to accept the invalid certificate. Once we do this and try to reopen the UCWA sample site we get the same cross domain error.

I would like to know if we can change the url to http within the api. Also assistance in making the anonymous chat work for my domain[or even metio.net] with in the sample code. Thank you anyone for helping me with this

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the location you are hosting your application to the allowed list of your company's SfB servers. I would assume you are hosting your application in localhost. Metio.net is whitelisted for that, hence it works for the metio.net environment.

-- Since I was flagged for pasting the relevant Url link last time with Microsoft published details, I am copying the content from the website ucwa.skype.com --

Allowed Domains

Allowed domains refers to those hosting a UCWA web application.

The samples will indicate that the host domain is not on the allowed list by alerting the following string, sent by the server in the headers of a 403 response:
Service does not allow a cross domain request from this origin.

Viewing the Allowed List

From the Skype for Business Server Management Shell on each server (front end, edge, and director), execute the following command:
Get-CsWebServiceConfiguration | select -ExpandProperty CrossDomainAuthorizationList

Editing the Allowed List

From the Skype for Business Server Management Shell on each server (front end, edge, and director), execute the following commands (replacing the text in {} with your values):
$x = New-CsWebOrigin -Url "https://apps.contoso.com"
Set-CsWebServiceConfiguration -Identity "{YOUR_IDENTITY}" -CrossDomainAuthorizationList @{Add=$x}

If you do not know the value of Identity for your Skype for Business Server, you can run the following command to see all identities configured on the server:
Get-CsWebServiceConfiguration | select identity

Comment: At the companies office we are running Skype for business online and when I brought this solution to the IT attention he said he was unable to add our domain to the allowed list since it could break Skype for business for the entire office.